# Why AFURLRequestSerialization use KVO to observe value changing?

Tags: afnetworking, alamofire, afnetworking-3

After reading the source code of `AFURLRequestSerialization`, I found that the author uses `AFHTTPRequestSerializerObservedKeyPaths` and `NSStringFromSelector` to get multiple keys such as `allowsCellularAccess` and `cachePolicy`, and uses itself as the observer to observe the value changing of these keys:

```
[self addObserver:self
       forKeyPath:keyPath
          options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
          context:AFHTTPRequestSerializerObserverContext];
```

Why doesn't he just override some setters and use setters to observe the value changing?

```
- (void)setAllowsCellularAccess:(BOOL)allowsCellularAccess {
    //here do something else
    _allowsCellularAccess = allowsCellularAccess;
}
```

Is there any benefits?